# acces denied when trying to get web.siteusers

Tags: powershell, spuser, runwithelevatedprivileges

I write a powershell script and when i try to get siteusers from certain SPWeb not all i have an access denied.
My spweb object is correctly retrieve because i can display $web.Url

```
    $webapps = Get-SPWebApplication

$userToReplace = $null
foreach($webapp in $webapps) {
    if($userToReplace -ne $null){
        break
    }
    $webappName = $webapp.DisplayName
    Write-Output "webapp: $webappName"

    foreach($sc in $webapp.Sites){

            $siteUrl = $sc.Url  
            #Write-Output "siteUrl: $siteUrl"

            $spsite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
            $web = $spsite.openweb()
            Write-Output $web.Url

            $siteUsers = $web.SiteUsers 
            #here is empty and an exception with acces denied occurs when trying to loop throw the collection
                foreach($user in $siteUsers){ 
                Write-Output $user.LoginName  
                }

    }
}
```

-I've tried to put my code between elevated privilege but still doesn't workd

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({});
```

-I ran my script as administrator
-I added policy on all web app with full control
-I used command:

```
Get-SPShellAdmin | Add-SPShellAdmin -UserName domain\user
```

Nothing of this solutions worked

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have access as a site collection owner? My experience is that it is not sufficient with permission through Add-SPShellAdmin. You need to have site collection administrator permissions on the current site collection as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question as per the StackExchange standards. Please check [answer]. If you are facing any issue with your code then you can ask a new question describing your problem. Check [ask]

Comment: Hi! I realized that. I tried to "add a comment" on the original post but I got a message that "You must have 50 reputation to comment". So my only way to reply, that I found, to this post was via "Answer". How should I otherwise have done to participate in this discussion?

I also tried to find how to send this as a private message to you @YashSaraiya , but I could not find a way through this forum. I'm quite new to this...

Comment: Yes. That's absolutely true and that's why it's important to gain trust of this forum by involving yourself and gaining reputation points first. That's the only reason why I haven't down-voted your answer which if a user with sufficient reputation points would have suffered from.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your respons @YashSaraiya Now I understand. Feel free to erase this dialogue about comments/answers if you have that access.